# how to add field to `auth_user_groups` table in django?

Tags: django, django-models

In my Django project I have users that every user may have different permission (some one has only read permission but others may be both read and write permissions) I want to add `permissions` field to django `auth_user_groups` table like this:

[image]
here is my models.py:

```
from django.db.models import *
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from django.db.models.signals import post_save


class MyUser(Model):
    user = OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
    Volume = IntegerField(default=5*1024*1024)


def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        profile, created = MyUser.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User, dispatch_uid="create_profile")
```

is it possible to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to create an additional table with an one-to-one relationship to `auth_user_groups` to solve your issue rather than fiddling with that. This is a similar approach as [the one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) suggested in the docs. Alternatively you would have to do a lot of work in order to provide your own models.

EDIT: Following up on the first comment: It is not possible to expose this model as the respective many-to-many field of the `User` model does not use an explicit [intermediate model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany) (in fact the many-to-many field belongs to `PermissionsMixin`, from which `AbstractUser` is derived, from which `User` is derived).

An [one-to-one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#ref-onetoone) field is essentially a many-to-one foreign key with `unique=True`. Therefore, you could instead create two foreign keys, one for User and one for Group with `unique_together` and then use these.

Comment: thank you. but how can I create a `OneToOneField` to `auth_user_groups` table? I mean what is its name that I can import ? (like `from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group` what is the name of that? I tried `from django.contrib.auth.models import UserGroups` but it is incorrect)

Answer (score 0):

Django provides permission to to group of users and individual users, You can create multiple groups and assign permissions to those groups. And assign groups to each user. So user withina a particular group will have same set of permissions.

Refer here for more https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization

Comment: thank you. all groups in my project have same permisions (read, read|write). but users in them may have read or read|write permission.this can't be handle with what you say.